# Skip folders to build using scons after full build

Tags: c, scons

I have large number of source files ~10,000 and they are scattered across several folders.

I wanted to know if there is a way to skip certain folders, I know that havent changed.

For ex, consider the following folder structure

```
A (Sconstruct is here)
|
->B (unchanged 1000 files)
->C (unchanged 1000 files)
->D (changed 1 file)
```

Once I do a complete build for the first time, I want it to compile everything (B, C, D) but when I modify a file in D (I know that), I would like to build folder **D only**, skip B and C and finally link them all together to form the final binary (B, C and new D).

I have been looking for quite some time now but not able to figure it out. Is it even possible? Can I specify only to look into a particular folder for changes?

Comment: You've just described **exactly what scons does**. If you run "scons", and subsequently change one file, then run "scons" again, scons only recompiles that one file and no others.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: correct, but it also traverses through dir B and C and looks for modified files. As a user, I know they havent changed, so how do i make scons skip those folders altogether.

Comment: So your complaint isn't that scons builds in B and C, it is that scons tests the dependencies in B and C. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Along with skipping dependencies ( which  I disabled using --implicit-deps-unchanged), I also want to disable traversing through B and C altogether (which takes a huge amount of time just to find out nothing changed).

In the end, I want to link B, C and new D together to the executable.

Comment: I have a question: if you build everything from scratch in the first run and then subsequently, and all by yourself, always know exactly which libraries/targets you have to rebuild based on your latest source code changes...what do you need a build system for? Why not using a simple script?

Comment: So D depends on B and C?  And you want SCons to ignore that fact and not check for updates?  Are you open to a command line flag which you'd use to avoid calling SConscript for those directories?

Comment: No D is independent of B and C thats why I dont need scons to evaluate these directories. I would prefer to be able to skip everything but D and then do the final linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd investigate using `Decider('timestamp-match')` or even building a custom `Decider` function. That should speed up your dependency-checking time.

But to answer your specific question, yes it is possible to not build the targets in `B` and `C`. If you don't invoke a builder for the targets in those subdirectories, you just won't build them. Just have an `if` that selectively chooses which `env.Object()` (or similar) functions to invoke.

When I fleshed out your example, I chose to have each subdirectory create a library that would be linked into the main executable, and to only invoke `env.SConscript()` for the directories that the user chooses. Here is one way to implement that:

A/SConstruct:

```
subdirs = ['B','C','D']
AddOption('--exclude', default=[], action='append', choices=subdirs)
env = Environment(EXCLUDES = GetOption('exclude'))

env.SConscript(
    dirs=[subdir for subdir in subdirs
          if subdir not in env['EXCLUDES']],
    exports='env')

env2 = env.Clone()
env2.PrependUnique(LIBPATH=subdirs,
                   LIBS=subdirs)
env2.Program('main.c')
```

B/SConscript:

```
Import('env')
env.Library('B', env.Glob('*.c'))
```

C/SConscript:

```
Import('env')
env.Library('C', env.Glob('*.c'))
```

D/SConscript:

```
Import('env')
env.Library('D', env.Glob('*.c'))
```

To do a global build: `scons`

To do a build after modifying a single file in `D`: `scons --exclude=B --exclude=C`

### EDIT

Similarly, you can add a whitelist option to your SConstruct. The idea is the same: only invoke builders for certain objects.

Here is a SConstruct similar to above, but with a whitelist option:

```
subdirs = ['B','C','D']
AddOption('--only', default=[], action='append', choices=subdirs)
env = Environment(ONLY = GetOption('only') or subdirs)

env.SConscript(
    dirs=env['ONLY'],
    exports='env')

env2 = env.Clone()
env2.PrependUnique(LIBPATH=subdirs,
                   LIBS=subdirs)
env2.Program('main.c')
```

To build everything: `scons`

To rebuild `D` and relink main program: `scons --only=D`

Comment: It is just that there are too many B's and C's, I need a way to white-list rather than black-list. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If D is independent of B and C just specify your target in D (program/library), or the whole directory, as target explicitly on the command line like `scons D/myprog.exe`. SCons will expand the required dependencies automatically, and such doesn't traverse the unrelated folders B and C.

Note how you can specify an arbitrary number of targets, so

```
scons D/myprog.exe B
```

is allowed too.